# MongoDB & Javascript how do i access an array of objects and match a specific key

Tags: javascript, mongodb

so i'm trying to match if the orders.id match by UserModel.find() then it should return that array.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNjgW.png

For example, 
I have two elements inside orders array, i need to check which one is equal to that id and then return that element that's equal to this.
So it should return
orders of index 0 and it's elements

I tried this:

```
userModel.find({ orders.id: orderID });
```

but it doesn't return the element

Answer (score 1):

First, I would add quotes to the field "order.id":

```
userModel.find({ "orders.id": orderID });
```

Second, I also see several spaces on the "ObjectId"

[object ids with string at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhU3J.png)

So this object id seems to be stored wrong as well. Check the reason that stored those spaces at the end of the object id.

Just in case you may test this query on the Mongo Compass or any other client would like.

Comment: It doesn't return that elements. It returns the whole user

Comment: You have to use the `find` method's [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#projection) parameter to return the only required fields.